# Issue using remote method in jquery validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation, jquery-validate

I'm following [this](http://alittlecode.com/jquery-form-validation-with-styles-from-twitter-bootstrap/) article in order to validate my form

My problem is when I have to use the `remote` method, e.g. `remote: "check-username.php"`

Since the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote) for remote method is not so clear for me, I would know:

How I need to structure my json output in php script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need JSON. You can put any text. For example you can

```
echo "success";
```

for passed validation, and enter validation message like:

```
echo "Username already exists.";
```

for failed validation.

In your callback do something like this:

```
remote: {
           url: "check-username.php" ,
           type: "post" ,
           data: {
              username: function() {
              return $("#username").val();
           },
           complete: function(data){
                if( data.responseText != "success" ) {
                   alert(data.responseText);
                   //handle failed validation
                }
             }
         }
```

Comment: Thank you @argonius. I implemented I little variation than your suggestion. I returned true instead of success.

Comment: "true" is required, not "success",also the data:{} is not needed if the field name is 'username'

Comment: the right answer is the manta's one, the server should respond with "true" or "false"

Answer (score 15):

To use the default method for `remote`, the remote page must respond with a string value of `"true"` or `"false"`.

**Valid** (*success*) Must be:

```
echo "true";
```

**Invalid** (*failure*):

```
echo "false"; // this can be any false. eg: 0 , "" , NULL.
```

The response will be evaluated as JSON.

To apply an error message, other than the default for a remote response of invalid ("false"), add the input name to the validator options `messages` object like so.

```
rules:{
    username:{
        remote: "check-username.php"
    }
},   
messages:{
    username:{
        remote: jQuery.format('{0} is already in use, please choose a different name')
    }
}
```

Comment: i received an error/warning 'jQuery.format' is deprecated.  use jQuery.validator.format instead.  which worked for me.  thanks

Comment: Great finally the right answer!!
the problem was in the server response, the right way is to return or echo "true" or "false" 
Thank you!

Comment: sorry for late comment.... so if email exists already, 'false' is sent? I'm a bit confused..